# best practice for directory polling

Tags: java, batch-processing

I have to do batch processing to automate business process. I have to poll directory at regular interval to detect new files and do processing. While old files is being processed, new files can come in. For now, I use quartz scheduler and thread synchronization to ensure that only one thread can process files.

Part of the code are:

application-context.xml

```
<bean id="methodInvokingJob"
  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean"><br/>
  <property name="targetObject" ref="documentProcessor" /><br/>
  <property name="targetMethod" value="processDocuments" /><br/>
</bean>
```

DocumentProcessor
.....

```
public void processDocuments() { 
  LOG.info(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " attempt to run.");
  if (!processing) {
     synchronized (this) {
        try {
           processing = true;
           LOG.info(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is processing");
           List<String> xmlDocuments = documentManager.getFileNamesFromFolder(incomingFolderPath);               
           // loop over the files and processed unlock files.
           for (String xmlDocument : xmlDocuments) {
              processDocument(xmlDocument);
           }
        }
        finally {
           processing = false;
        }
     }
  }
}
```

For the current code, I have to prevent other thread to process files when one thread is processing. Is that a good idea ? or we support multi-threaded processing. In that case how can I know which files is being process and which files has just arrived ? Any idea is really appreciated.

Comment: You tagged this C#, but your code looks like Java. Please make sure you specify the right language and OS.

Comment: It looks like somebody else erroneously put in the C# tag, so I changed it to Java. Still, we need to know the OS to give a useful answer.

Comment: Thanks gabe, it's batch processing in java. How can you format the code ?

Answer (score 5):

I would build it with these parts:

1. [Castle Transactions with TxF](http://github.com/haf/Castle.Services.Transaction)
2. [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) [JavaVersion](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/)
3. TransactionScope (no java version unless you hack it a lot)
4. [A lock-free queue](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/CommentView,guid,3740daff-a459-4298-bc9b-65d3647f5c0d.aspx) * (Paper discussing perf Java vs .Net, might be able to get source [from them for Java](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/4283719/4283720/04283864.pdf?arnumber=4283864)) [Java lock-based queues](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/implementations/queue.html)

   Such that:

When there's a new file, the file system watcher detects it (remember to put the correct flags, handle the error condition and set Enbled <- True and watch out for doubles), puts the file path in the queue.

You have an application thread, n worker threads. If this is the only app, they spin-wait on the queue, TryDequeue, otherwise they block on a monitor while(!Monitor.Enter(has_items)) ;

When a worker threads get a path through the de-queue operation, it starts working on it, and now no other thread can work on it. If there are doubles of output (depending on your setup), you can then use a file transaction as you are writing the output file. If the Commit operation fails, then you know another thread has already written the output file, and resume polling the queue.

- Race condition, see: http://groups.google.com/group/lock-free/browse_thread/thread/c3b83466b27f6372

Comment: Thanks for the info Henrik, all the mentioned library are completely new to me but I must definitely ensure the transaction so I will look into TxF. For now, I intend to use Spring Batch + Spring Integration. I just read through the introduction and some demo but they all convinced me that it's the right solution to chase.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do the following:

- One thread that gets your filenames and adds them to a synchronized queue.
- Multiple threads to do the actual reading: get an item from the synced queue and process it.

To check if a file is used you can simply try to rename/move it.

Comment: We did something just like that.
We also kept in memory cache to check which files are currently being consumed