# Running java program one after the other

Tags: java

What i have completed:

1. upload it to server
2. download from server

download should happen only if upload is done. I have the code to do it as separate java classes.
What i need to do is.

For every hour upload should be done in the 1st half hour and only if upload is done , in the next 1/2 hour download should be done.and again after download upload should be done.

Comment: use a FLAG , set it to COMPLETE when UPLOAD is done , in download program check for FLAG , if COMPLETE only then begin downloading , else do nothing

Comment: put Thread.sleep(<Set your time>); After each class execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a typical Producer/Consumer Synchronization Problem:

You can use a flag or you can use a observable/observer pattern to synchronize this.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a `Thread.wait()` on each Thread. After you have finished a Thread call `notify()` to release and start working

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with files take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2400612/68969) answer, you may be be able to use [JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/) to listen to file system events, such as: